# Systemd boot menu not showing after Windows 11 22H2 version update

Tags: multi-boot, windows-update, windows-11, systemd, pop-os

I built my PC to be able to start a Windows 11 partition alongside a Pop_os one. But yesterday, I decided to make the 22H2 windows 11 update, and since then, the systemd boot menu isn't showing anymore when I start my PC.

Can someone help me to make this menu show up again on boot? Don't hesitate to ask for further information.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Have you checked what bootloader WAS doing the boot loading before and which is doing it after the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are going to see this question, you should know that I resolved it by myself. What I did :

- My linux partition looks like it disapears from my computer as I wasn't able to see it through BIOS or `efibootmgr` command in terminal, but, on the other hand, I was also able to see the disk partition through Pop!_os live usb. So I keep searching to figure the problem out.
- I find this page and this [comment](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1733171#p1733171) in particular. At this very precise moment, I was looking for this keywords in Google : "efi choose boot partition timeout systemd" (as I knew that systemd dual boot screen is configurable through a system config file).
- So I did everything the guy said: `efibootmgr`, `bootctl status`, I `cated` the configuration files and finally, I typed this command `bootctl install` which instantly solved my problem.
- So I fiounded back the "timeouted" dual boot screen on my computer loading !

Answer (score 0):

Go to your computer's firmware settings – in the "boot order" section, you should be able to move "`Linux Boot Manager`" above the Windows entry.

Alternatively, use the "Boot menu" key (usually F8 or F9 or F10 or F12...) to access the computer's one-time boot menu and select systemd-boot from there. Once you're in Linux, use `efibootmgr --bootorder ...` to select systemd-boot as the first entry to use.

Alternatively, from within Windows, run `bcdedit /enum firmware` to check whether the "Linux Boot Manager" entry is present; copy its GUID from the `identifier {guid-goes-here}` line and use `bcdedit /set "{fwbootmgr}" displayorder "{guid-goes-here}"` to make it primary again.

Comment: HI, I tried everything you suggested but : 1- I don't have any "Linux Boot Manager" in my computer's BIOS, only the windows one. 2- Using the advanced booting settings on windows to access the BIOS boot menu on startup, I was not able to see the Pop!_os booting option. 3- Within Windows, the "Linux Boot Manager" entry is not present when I type the command you gave me. 4- I've checked if my Pop!_Os partition is still on my disk and yes, both "/dev/nvme0n1p1" and "/dev/nvme0n1p2" are in the GParted utility when I boot on the live USB key.